# (Java) Pass a parameter from a constructor to all the methods of a class

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

Say I have two methods in class 1. Can I pass a parameter to class 1 constructor which would then pass the parameter to both of the methods? Something like the example code below:

```
class stuff{
    int c;
    stuff(x){
        c = x;
    }

    public static int sum(int a, int b){
        stuff self = new stuff();
        return c*(a + b);
    }

public static int mult(int a, int b){
    return c*(a*b);
}
}

class test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    stuff foo = new stuff(5);
    System.out.println(stuff.sum(1, 2));
    System.out.println(stuff.mult(1, 2));
    }
}
```

So from class test I want to access both methods from class stuff, while passing the parameters for the methods, but I also want to pass a global class parameter (5 in this case). How can I do this?

Comment: You already do what you describe. Have you tried it? What is the problem when trying it? I recommend you to do some tutorials for Java classes.

Comment: So you mean having a getter method for variable c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First two important things :

- Constructors are designed to create instances.
- Class names should start with an uppercase.

As you write :

```
class Stuff{
    int c;
    Stuff(x){
        c = x;
    }
    ...
 }
```

Here you assign `x` to a `c` field.
But `sum()` and `mult()` are static methods.
They cannot use the `c` field.
Make these methods instances methods and you could use `c` in these methods.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Stuff foo = new Stuff(5);
    System.out.println(foo.sum(1, 2));
    System.out.println(foo.mult(1, 2));
}
```

And use the current instance in these instance methods to sum or multiply current value with passed parameter values :

```
public int sum(int a, int b){
    return c*(a + b);
}

public int mult(int a, int b){
    return c*(a*b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove 'static' keyword from your methods, and do not create new instance of 'stuff' in a sum method. Instead just create instance of stuff in test#main method like you do right now, and it will work like you wanted.